# How to calculate the test results pass percentage in XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt-1.0

The input is an XML file

```
<test-results name="project name" total="73" errors="0" failures="43" not-run="0" inconclusive="0" ignored="0" skipped="0" invalid="0" date="2016-01-05" time="20:32:22">
.......
</test-results>
```

I want to calculate the "No of pass results" and "Pass Percentage". I have done with the No of pass results. It is working fine

```
               <tr>
                <td>Number of Passes</td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:variable name="failures" select="@failures"/>
                  <xsl:variable name="total" select="@total"/>
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$failures != ''">
                      <xsl:value-of select="($total - $failures)"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:value-of select="@total"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </td>
              </tr>
```

Now I want to calculate the pass percentage(eg :- 87.45%). I tried the below logic. but it is throwing an exception

```
<tr>
        <td>Success Rate</td>
        <td>
          <xsl:variable name="Pass" select="@total - @failures"/>
          <xsl:variable name="totalNo" select="@total"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="($Pass/$totalNo)*100"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Can anyone help me out to calculate the pass percentage?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which exception does it throw?

Comment: @Tomalak -  <xsl:value-of select="($Pass/@total)*100"/> - XSL Transformation exception(Runtime error)

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="($Pass/$totalNo)*100"/> - Unexcepted token - Compile time error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `div` operator instead of the `/` sign:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$Pass div $totalNo * 100"/>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine, but i need output with 2 decimal points with % appended (eg:- 87.45%)

Comment: @Vishnu  Use the `format-number()` function http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#format-number